# Django object change doesn't show op on page

Tags: django, caching

I've got an object, Question, that I've created an edit page for. This worked fine. Someone would edit the question and changes would show up on the page that just showed the question. Recently however, I started noticing the changes did NOT show up on the list of questions. This problem persists after having changed the cache-backend to the dummybackend. When running the developmentserver, I see the request with a nice 200 code. Print statements I put into the view, that I expected to show up in the output of de dev-server, do not show up. So apperently the view method isn't even called. I get the feeling the 200 code does not mean something wasn't retrieved from cache.

Three ways I noticed, make the website show the change in the object after it has been saved:

```
1. Signing the current user out of the website and then logging in again.
2. Appending ?something=whatever to the url.
3. Waiting for an unknown amount of time. I tried if the waitingtime could be changed by modifying session-parameters, but to no avail.
```

Though I think it is possible to use that last method, it doesn't feel right. And it means means quite a bit of work to solve a problem that wasn't there before. And I'd like to know just what happend.

Here is the cache-bit from settings.py. No surprises there I'd think:

```
    CACHES = {
        'default':{
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache'}}
```

And, because logging out & in helps, the session stuff:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True 
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60
```

Oh and this problem is also in the admin..
Suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked your browser cache and optionally disabled it?

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention that. Did that. Didn't help. At least not for Chrome (winxp & mac os x) and IE and Firefox (both winxp)